# WPF Data bindings not working after intiailize. No Binding Errors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I am having an issue with the data bindings between my `View` and `ViewModel`. The bindings only run at initialize and then they will not update. The code runs as expected and I have no binding errors per the output window, but the bindings on the UI will not update.

Program Setup:

- WPF
- C#
- Prism V8.1.97
- MVVM
- .NET Framework 4.7.2

Things I have tried:

- XAML set to bind directly to the property with `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- XAML set to Find the `RelativeSource` of type `UserControl`
- `RelayCommand` to update the UI, with and without `Invoke` to the main thread.
- `BackgroundWorker` to update the UI, with and without `Invoke` to the main thread.
- `DelegateCommand` to update the UI, with and without `Invoke` to the main thread.
- `i.Interaction.EventTriggers` with `Click` to Invoke a UI update on the main thread.

Everyone of these will run the code, but will not update the UI. I have left some of the code that I have tried in the program for `BackgroundWorker`, `Delegate void`, and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. I have written a few programs and have never had this issue. Did I setup something wrong when I created the program?

UPDATE: There seems to be an issue with Visual Studio 2019. This might be only on my version as the other programs I have written no longer work. This could would normally run as intended.

UserControl I am trying to do a simple binding with. I created a `Textbox` at the bottom with `Mode=TwoWay` to see if the `TextBlock` would update.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MRC.Module.ModStatus.Views.ModStatusManagerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MRC.Module.ModStatus.Views"
             
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"  
             
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:cconv="clr-namespace:MRC.Framework.Core.Data.Converters;assembly=MRC.Framework.Core"
             
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <cconv:RemoveSpacesConverter x:Key="IntToStringConvert"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#222222"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         
            <Border BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Button Height="20" Margin="0,6" Content="{Binding StartStop}" Width="100"
                                        >
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
                                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProgressCommand}" />
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </Button>
                                  
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock  Margin="5,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Health, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConvert}}" FontSize="16" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <TextBlock  Margin="5,0"  Text="{Binding TestingText}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" AutomationProperties.Name="TestText"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <!--
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Health, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                -->
                                <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Minimum="0"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="25" Margin="5" />

                                <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TestingText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16" Height="30" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                          
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                   
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Mod Status" 
                       FontSize="30" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind

```
  public partial class ModStatusManagerView : UserControl
    {
        public ModStatusManagerView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ModStatusManagerViewModel();
        }

       
    }
```

ViewModel

```
 public class ModStatusManagerViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        #region Variables
        private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        private delegate void UpdateUIDelgate(string health, string Status);
        #endregion

        #region Commands
         public ICommand ProgressCommand { get; private set; }
        private void Testing(string health, string Status)
        {
            try
            {
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            
        }

        private bool CanProgressExecute()
        {
            return true;
        }
        private void Progress()
        {
            try
            {


                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
                {

                    Health = 0;
                    StartStop = "Stop";
                    TestingText = "Initialized";

                    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
                    {
                        Health = i;
                        System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.UpdateLayout();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }

                    TestingText = "Completed";
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Complete");

                }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);

                /*if (!System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                {
                    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                       new UpdateUIDelgate(Testing), "Stop", "Initialized");
                    return;
                }*/


               // System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                   // new UpdateUIDelgate(Testing), "Stop", "Initialized");
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }       
        }


        public ICommand ProgressOffCommand { get; }
        private void ProgressOff()
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                StartStop = "Start";
            });
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public ModStatusManagerViewModel()
        {
            this.ProgressCommand = new RelayCommand(Progress);
            //this.ProgressOffCommand = new RelayCommand(ProgressOff);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _isEnabled, value); }
        }
        private bool _isEnabled = true;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Max Health
        /// </summary>
        public string StartStop
        {
            get { return _startStop; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _startStop, value); }
        }
        private string _startStop = "Start";



        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Max Health
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsOn
        {
            get { return _isOn; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _isOn, value); }
        }
        private bool _isOn = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Max Health
        /// </summary>
        public double MaxHealth
        {
            get { return _maxHealth; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _maxHealth, value); }
        }
        private double _maxHealth = 100;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Min Health
        /// </summary>
        public double MinHealth
        {
            get { return _minHealth; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _minHealth, value); }
        }
        private double _minHealth = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Min Health
        /// </summary>
        public double Health
        {
            get { return _Health; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _Health, value); }
        }
        private double _Health = 0;

        public string TestingText
        {
            get { return _testingText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _testingText, value); }
        }
        private string _testingText = "Waiting";
        #endregion

        #region Events

        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                while (IsOn)
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();

                    Health = rnd.Next(0, 100);

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
            }

        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                                   RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //update ui once worker complete his work
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

In case someone would like to see the implementation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : ModelBase
    {
        public ViewModelBase()
        {

        }
        ~ViewModelBase()
        {

        }

        public bool HasAnyErrors { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the `ModelBase` that `ViewModelBase` Implements

```
 public abstract class ModelBase : BindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected ModelBase()
        {

        }
        ~ModelBase() { }

        public bool HasIssues { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                typeof(ViewModelBase),
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Here is the `RelayCommand`

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {

        #region Private Members
        private Action _action;
        private Action<object> _actionOb;

        Action<object> _execteMethod;
        Func<object, bool> _canexecuteMethod;
        #endregion

        #region Public Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Basic Command
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = (sender, e) => { };
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action"></param>
        public RelayCommand(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        /*public RelayCommand(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Frames.Model.Category> category, Action<object> action)
        {
            _actionOb = action;
        }*/


        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor that passes an object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execteMethod"></param>
        /// <param name="canexecuteMethod"></param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execteMethod, Func<object, bool> canexecuteMethod)
        {
            _execteMethod = execteMethod;
            _canexecuteMethod = canexecuteMethod;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor that determines if an action can execute before executing
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action"></param>
        /// <param name="CanExecute"></param>
        public RelayCommand(Action action, bool CanExecute)
        {
            if (CanExecute)
                return;
            _action = action;
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> action, bool CanExecuteOb)
        {
            _actionOb = action;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Command Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns True if bool Parameter is not busy
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((bool)parameter)
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }


        }

        public bool CanExecuteOb(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes an Action that is not busy
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter"></param>
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                _action();
            });
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes an Action that is not busy with a <href="Param">
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="param"></param>
        public void ExecuteOb(object param)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                _actionOb(param);
            });
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: Be aware that `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TestingText}` is equivalent to `{Binding TestingText}`. However, it us usually wrong that a UserControl sets its own DataContext to a private view model object that is otherwise unknown to the application.

Comment: @Clemens I do know that those are equivalent, but I tried it both ways because I know XAML can be touchy. I am not sure what you mean about setting the DataContext to a private view model. This is how I have seen a lot of different people stating to do this. I have also had this work in other applications which is why I am confused.

Comment: "*A lot of different people*" - still it is plain wrong. Those lot of people are perhaps the reason why we see about one question per day where the asker made this mistake. How do you expect the rest of your application to interact with the UserControl, when it has a private view model that you don't know?

Comment: And do you really have `System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.UpdateLayout()` in a view model? Well, that is just terrible. A view model must not have any knowledge of specific view elements, even not that there is a MainWindow.

Comment: You must also not access `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher` in a view model. If you need a Dispatcher, derive the view model class from DispatcherObject, and instantiate it in the UI thread.

Comment: In this application I have multiple projects. I am learning the best I can and I appreciate your help. The view is bound to the Main Project Shell. I guess what I am getting to, is how is the best way to do what you are stating. Bind the data in the XAML of the main application so it isn't considered private?

Comment: Also, those point outs of the `System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.UpdateLayout()` and `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher` are not how I would normally construct the code, but those are attempts that I have made to update the UI and with no luck.

Comment: In your ModStatusManagerViewModel implementation, you change the properties with the SetProperty method.
But the implementations of ViewModelBase and ModelBase do not have this method.
If it is implemented in BindableBase, then from there it will not be able to raise the ModelBase.PropertyChanged event.
The OnPropertyChanged method is not called anywhere in your code.
Either you have shown implementations that do not match your code, or you have an incorrect implementation.

Comment: A UserControl would either expose bindable properties (like any other control in the framework) and not have knowledge of a view model at all. Or it would bind in its XAML against properties of an object in its DataContext. The value of the DataContext would be inherited from the parent element of the control, e.g. a ContentControl that uses a DataTemplate that contains a declaration of your control, and that has its Content property assigned an instance of the view model object.

Comment: @Clemens I just added an update. It seems there is something wrong with my visual studio because code that used to run just fine will not run as intended anymore.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: It seems the functionality of `SetProperty` has stopped working.

I changed my properties from

```
 public string TestingText
        {
            get { return _testingText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _testingText, value);}
        }
        private string _testingText = "Testing";
```

To

```
 public string TestingText
        {
            get { return _testingText; }
            set
            {
                if (_testingText == value)
                    return;
                _testingText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TestingText");
            }
        }
        private string _testingText = "Testing";
```

everything is now working as it should be.

Comment: `SetProperty` is working as expected, but it raises `BindableBase.PropertyChanged` which you override with `ModelBase.PropertyChanged`... Visual Studio even warns you about this.

Comment: This has never been an issue until last week. This is the first time, even with my current setup that it has stopped working and this is how I have seen plenty of people show on this platform on how to create that base.